# Slow jQuery animation - Changing width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two divs. One is currently 0% and the other 100%. With the click function, I transform them into 12% and 88%.

Works like charm, but I would like the "process" to be slow, and not instant. Like a small animation.

This is the code I have:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".menu_logo").click(function(){
    $(".right").css("width","88%");
    $(".left").css("width","12%");
    $(".menu_logo").css("display","none");
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS transitions. Add the following properties to your `.right` and `.left` classes.

**CSS**

```
-webkit-transition: width 150ms linear;
o-transition: width 150ms linear;
transition: width 150ms linear;
```

Comment: Great! Works like charm! I thought I had to touch the CSS... thanks a lot!! Regards.

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you don't have any more questions, consider marking it solved.

Answer (score 0):

To do this with jquery, you can use the following snip:

```
$("button").click(function() {$("div").animate({width:'350px'}, "slow")});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gqu4gako/)